# No payment methods when manually creating a Magento order in the backend?

Tags: magento

I use PayPal Web Payments (Standard) as my payment gateway, but when I try and create an order manually (so I can apply discounts for specific people etc), there are no payment methods in the list on the form. I'm experiencing the same problem as described in [this](http://208.86.253.124/boards/viewthread/23964/#t167994) thread in 2008 (except we're now in 2012 and I'm using the latest stable release of Magento.

Any ideas? Are there any quick code fixes to make the payment methods appear? Ideally I'd have the sales order be sent to the email address specified upon creating the order, whilst also receiving a copy (as per normal orders) to my sales email address.

Has anyone else experienced (and overcome) this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that these variables are according to your choice

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
```

The first variable allows the payment method to be used in the backend if set to true. The second blocks it from being used in the frontend if set to false.

Comment: Which file do you make this changes in?

Comment: Pretty sure it's in the class that inherits the model Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract in your custom payment module :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with shipping methods on admin side. I enabled free shipping method, it appeared in the admin.

May be try enabling Check/MoneyOrder method for payments. If that appears on the admin side, you can atleast proceed with creating the order.